# How to add tooltip in kendo combobox?

Tags: angular, typescript, kendo-ui, kendo-ui-angular2, kendo-combobox

Check [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/kendo-combobox-angular?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts) project and suggest how to add tooltips to the dropdown, so that I am able to see tooltips for 'Small,' 'Medium,' and 'Large' dropdowns which is mentioned in StackBlitz project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define a template for the items of the combobox, specifically `kendoComboBoxItemTemplate`.

Place the following inside your combobox:

```
<kendo-combobox [allowCustom]="true"
                [data]="data"
                [textField]="'text'"
                [valueField]="'value'"
                [filterable]="true"
                (filterChange)="handleFilter($event)"
                [placeholder]="'T-shirt size'">
    <ng-template kendoComboBoxItemTemplate let-dataItem>
        <div [title]="dataItem.text">{{dataItem.text}}</div>
    </ng-template>
</kendo-combobox>
```

You can place anything you want or need in the `title` attribute to serve as a tooltip.

Comment: Sometimes undefined tooltip coming on mouse over on left arrow which is nothing but .k-select class, how to hide tooltip from that arrow ? @shai

Comment: I don't really know what arrow you're talking about... Can you add a photo to the question or maybe ask a new question for this issue?